# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') at _overpassJSON2geoJSON

Tags: reactjs, openstreetmap

I'm trying to fetch data from openstreetmap using Fetch API in reactjs using the following code:

```
const url = 'https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/map';

const getRequestData = async (values) => {
  await fetch(
    `${url}?bbox=${values.left},${values.bottom},${values.right},${values.top}`
  ).then((res) => osmtogeojson(res));
};

export default getRequestData;
```

I cannot figure out what is wrong here any help!.

Comment: `osmtogeojson` doesn't like the parameter you are passing to it. What does it expect? Currently you're giving it the fetch response object... which isn't the fetched data.

Comment: as I understand it expects osm data. So is this means that I should first convert the res object to osm?

Comment: but actually, this URL in the documentation of OpenStreetMap should return osm data! or am I missing something?

Comment: fetch doesn't know what osmtogeojson wants. What you passed it was a response object, which doesn't contain the data of the request. "osm data" isn't a javascript data type. If what you actually mean is a javascript object, then you need to wait and process the response data as json, and then pass the resulting object/array to your function.

Comment: would you please help me with parsing XML data in reactjs after searching I found out that OpenStreetMap returns content type text/XML and I think I need to parse this before passing it to osmtogeojson function

Comment: I tried to use res.json() but I got this error:
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: Solved thanks actually changing to Axios and adding content-type = application/xml solved my problems now I can you osmtogeojson.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For some reason fetch api didn't work with me here so to solve it I used axios in this way:

```
const getRequestData = async (values) => {
  axios.get(
    `${url}?bbox=${values.left},${values.bottom},${values.right},${values.top}`,
    {
      "Content-Type": "application/xml; charset=utf-8"

    }
  ).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data)
    let result = osmtogeojson(response.data);
    console.log(result);
  });
};
```